# jquery sorting plugins similar to big.dk?

Tags: jquery

Ive been googling around for a plugin that would sort images similar to http://big.dk/#projects, but without success. Does anyone know if a similar plugin exists? Or do i need to start from scratch? Didnt feel like re-inventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isotope may be what you're looking for: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html